# Error Detection

Tags: word-choice

#### Multiple Choice Error Detection

One of the four options is grammatically incorrect.

#### Sentence

> **Without** green plants, the sun's energy **could not be used** on the earth, and all **other** organisms **live** on the earth would die.

#### Choices

1. *Without*
2. *could not be used*
3. *other*
4. *live*

I think the third is the correct answer (wrong grammar = correct answer).

Comment: A question about what's appropriate to ask should be asked on [meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/). (I suggest asking it there and deleting this one or flagging it for delete.)  Also, don't ask the same questions on both of [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) and [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @jwpat7 hi, as you see, there is one sample concrete question, Which is more suitable? ELL or ELU?

Comment: I don't understand how the  sample question works – ie whether the answer should be a letter, several letters, etc – but that aside, I suggest ELL.  Also see [on-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page.

Comment: Your "seems true" addendum seems strange to me.  I would assume that the hidden error would not be in the veracity of the statement but in the grammar- i.e. one or more of A,B,C, or D is in error.  Having said that, I think you ought to tell us what your thoughts are on why any of A,B,C, or D might be questionable and we can comment.  I don't think it's appropriate for us to blindly answer questions from the textbook.

Comment: @Jim well,I edited, how about this.

Comment: Better.  What about [D] seems funny to you?  If "live" doesn't sound right, what is another possibility?

Comment: @Jim I think D is right,,, and just now I found maybe the problem of C `other`, and `the other`?

Comment: @Jim how many sentences like such a question is appropriate in my post? The original question, I put that here Meta.http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/error-detection-of-sentences

Comment: @HyperGroups,  How this question is presented and formatted now, makes a LOT more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third one is not incorrect.

Both 'all other' and 'all the other' are acceptable English in the context, though I would lean towards *all other* as most correct.  'All the other' feels like it's referring to individual organisms, not whole classes of organisms which is the intent of the sentence.

The fourth one is the most wrong answer. There is a definite tense issue at play. This page has a fairly comprehensive [Table of Tenses](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/tenses) that looks correct (I only skimmed the content). This should point out a more correct word.

Comment: Most likely #4 is only "wrong" because OP has failed to transcribe the word ***that*** from the original context. But frankly, such questions don't seem at all appropriate for ELL.

Comment: Actually, I think #4 is incorrect, but it's because the word should read _living_, not _live_. Fumble's suggestion works, too, but I the test writers were aiming at the distinction between _live_ and _living_.

Comment: @J.R. and *alive*, too.

Comment: @Stoney: _alive_ works, too, which is why I think this is a bad test question. Still, I'd wager that the test writers were trying to wrongly conjugate a verb, and have that be the reason for the "correct" answer. They did an especially poor job, for the reasons you & Fumble have pointed out. Like in so many other "Help me on my ESL prep test question" questions, we've ended up talking about how bad the question is, more than we do about the English itself. At least future visitors will know not to read too much into these test questions.